# GTHUMB crashes soon after starting to display folder full of JPG images

Tags: crash, gthumb

I have a number of IP cameras that send their images to one of the computers on my network.  They have been working fine for years and the images are visible three of the four computers I use to access them.  On the fourth, an ASUS laptop, the image directory begins to display but then GTHUMB crashes with the following message:

```
gthumb: ../../../../src/cairo-surface.c:930: cairo_surface_reference: 
Assertion 'CAIRO_REFERENCE_COUNT_HAS_REFERENCE (&surface->ref_count)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A similar problem is reported [in this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gthumb/-/issues/143) from over a year ago. Perhaps you could report it as a bug as well, encouraging more developers to look at the issue? Be sure to include as much detail as possible, such as the number of images in the directory and whatnot 

Comment: Thank you, matigo.